# Output redirection hangs if process has spawned a background fork of xclip

Tags: bash, pipe, zsh, pipeline, xclip

I've got a script which calls to `xclip` inside. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
RESULT="some data"
echo $RESULT | xclip
echo $RESULT
```

`xclip` puts puts the data from its stdin to the clipboard, spawns a background thread to preserve that buffer (that's how clipboard works in X11) and detaches it from tty.

If I run a script directly, it works as expected:

```
$ ./script.sh
some data
$
```

However, if I'll try to pass it's output into a pipeline, it hangs until `xclip` background process ends (basically, until someone else puts data into the clipboard).

```
$ ./script.sh | ./another_script.sh # it hangs
```

I found that `xclip` has a `-f` flag which seem to fix that problem.

From the man page:

> when xclip is invoked in the in mode with output level set to silent (the defaults), the filter option will cause xclip to print the text  piped  to  standard  in
>                 back to standard out unmodified

However, I'm trying to understand why does it work that way.

I've created another example which behaves the same way:

`echo $(sleep 5 &)`

Also, I've been told that in `fish` my example works without `-f` flag.

So, the question is:
 1. Is this a bug of a shell (`bash` and `zsh`) or an expected behaviour?
 2. How does `-f` flag affects that behaviour? From the man page, it does not seems very related.
3. How to make other scripts (e.g. `sleep`) work the way `xclip` works with `-f` flag?

Comment: `$RESULT="some data"` -> `RESULT="some data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default,

1. all open files are passed from a parent process to child process. AND
2. When a pipe is created (A->B), process B will not get the EOF indicator on stdin, until ALL processes from step A close their STDOUT.

Combining the above, when you execute `/script.sh | ./another_script.sh`, the backgrounded `xclip` will inherit the 'script.sh' stdout (which is the input to `./another_script.sh`), at this time, there are two processes (script.sh, xclip) which are connected to the pipe. Only when both will close STDOUT (or will terminate), the `./another_script.sh` will see the EOF on the pipe, and will be able to exit (assuming it's waiting for EOF on input).

The solution for those cases is for the back-grounded process to close stdout, therefore allowing pipelines to complete. Usually, the stdout will be redirected to stderr, if output is needed.  Most likely, the '-f' closes the STDOUT.

Per man `xclip`, possible to write `echo $RESULT | xclip -f` (no need for extra echo) to avoid the problem, and allow script to run as part of a pipeline

man `fork` and man `pipe` provides the details. In particular

man 2 fork:

> - The  child  inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors.  Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same
>       open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in the parent.  This means that the two file  descrip‐
>       tors  share open file status flags, file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and
>     F_SETSIG
>       in fcntl(2)).

man 7 pipe:

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed,
>         then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe  will  see
>         end-of-file  (read(2)  will  return  0).

Comment: So something like `{ echo $RESULT | xclip; } >/dev/null` fix it?

Comment: I'm not able to verify this. Per man page, looks like 'xclip -f' performs the above function, making it possible to use it as part of a pipeline. I'll extend the answer.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination. Would appreciate if you'll add some links or quotes from man pages describing this behaviour.

Comment: See also: [xclip does not close STDOUT, might be a problem](https://github.com/g6ai/dotfiles/issues/1)